# How can create a project in playframework in a specifi version?

Tags: playframework

I want to create a project in version 2.3.X in play framework, but when I execute the command `sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8` I cannot choose the version and I find a play framework in version 2.8.X
How can set a specific version?

Comment: You can then create Play app with 2.3 version and update the Play plugin version in `plugins.sbt` -  to `"com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % % "2.8.0"` version.

Comment: Consider that is a downgrade. I create a play in version 2.8.X and i want to have a 2.3.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-b, --branch` option to choose from a specific branch of a g8 template:

```
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8 --branch 2.5.x
```

Unfortunately, version 2.5.x is the oldest branch existing for the play-java-seed project.

You can either downgrade a 2.5.x project or start from scratch by following the instructions here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication#Create-a-new-application-without-Activator